# How do I have an option be the placeholder and force selection?

Tags: react-select

Is it possible to have a preset value so that 'Select...' does not exist? Currently, the selectValue is set to placeholder text, but what if I want no placeholder text, the select component to initially be one of the options to select and there to be no placeholder option?

Is this possible, if so, how do I do it with React-select? I've been attempting to read the docs and discover a way. On the React-select demo page, there is no example that has a preselected value that disables the ability to see a placeholder option and instead only has a selection of a default option or option selected, and if backspaced, goes to default selection.

This is my first time using React-select so please take it easy on me, trying to learn how to use it. Also going to post another question about how to override the style package, because the docs don't give a clear example of how to do such. Thanks!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import ReactSelect from 'react-select'

export default class Select extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
   options: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  })),
  name: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  cb: PropTypes.func
}

state = {
 selectValue: ''
}

handleChange = (value) => (
 this.setState({selectValue: value}, () => {
   if (this.props.cb) {
    this.props.cb(this.state.selectValue)
   }
 })
)

render () {
 const {options, name, placeholder} = this.props
 const {selectValue} = this.state

 return (
   <ReactSelect
     name={name}
     placeholder={selectValue !== '' ? selectValue.value : placeholder}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     selectValue={selectValue}
     selectClear='false'
     options={options}
   />
  )
 }
}
```

[image: I want to force the user to chose between CA and NV, no Select default]

I want to force the user to chose between CA and NV, no Select default

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-select then you just need to put `placeholder=""` and it will be done. No default would be shown.

It automatically shows the selected value. if there is none the placeholder would be shown which is empty in this condition. You don't need to define any states yourself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an option to be selected by default by using the [defaultValue](https://react-select.com/props) prop. The placeholder will never be shown by doing this.

```
<ReactSelect
  ...
  options={options}
  defaultValue={options[0]}
/>
```